# Can't build Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I’m running docker [Docker 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a] on an Ubuntu 18 machine.

Simply carrying out a very simple exercise from docker in order to build a dockerfile : https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

On running the following command

```
docker build -t helloapp .
```

I get the following error

```
error checking context: 'can't stat '/home/aielloine/.docker/helloapp/dockerfiles''.
```

The docker file:

```
FROM busybox
COPY /hello
RUN cat /hello
```

Comment: Can you add your actual Dockerfile to the question?

Comment: please add your Dockerfile

Comment: see at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/ COPY reference

Comment: The COPY statement requires at least two arguments. You need to specify what file/directory from the host you're copying to the container image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the source, i.e. the file you want to copy inside the iamge, in your `COPY` command:

```
FROM busybox
COPY <source> /hello
#      ^
#      |
#  This is missing
RUN cat /hello
```